# Log4Net Store file in AppData with Date Folders

Tags: c#, .net, logging, error-handling, log4net

I am trying to store a log4net file in the Local AppData Directory with the year and month in the folder structure also using the log4net config file. For example such as:

C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\CompanyName\ApplicationName\logs\[Year]\[Month]\yyyyMMdd.log

Where [Year] is the current year and [Month] is the current Month.

I currently have the following:

```
<file value="${LocalAppData}\\CompanyName\\ApplicationName\\logs\\" />
```

But i dont know how to get the year and month in. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use rolling file appender in your config

```
<appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="Logging\\MWLog"/>
  <appendToFile value="true"/>
  <rollingStyle value="Composite"/>
  <datePattern value="-yyyyMMdd"/>
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="-1"/>
  <maximumFileSize value="1MB"/>
  <countDirection value="1"/>
  <encoding value="utf-8"/>
  <staticLogFileName value="false"/>
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date{HH:mm:ss.fff}|%-5level|%message%newline"/>
  </layout>
</appender>
```